# Не получается использовать import'ы из es6 в node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, node-modules

Не получается подключить модули с помощью `import ... from ...`.
Если я правильно понимаю, то для использования синтаксиса es6 в nodejs 10 мне не нужно больше указывать никаких флагов.

Версия:

```
$ node -v
v10.1.0
```

Пример кода:

```
$ node -i
> import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as fs from 'fs';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

> import fs from 'fs';
import fs from 'fs';
       ^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Вопрос: Что я делаю не так? Как правильно мне импортировать модули с использованием `import ... from ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы использовать эти функции нужно запускать node с флагом.

```
node --experimental-modules my-app.js
```

Более подробно можете узнать в документации

```
https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html
```

Comment: Как оказалось все намного хуже. У меня отсутствовало понимание того, что `es6 modules` это не то, что `CJS`. В итоге я пытался делать странные вещи... Перешел пока на использование модуля `esm`. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Для таво, чтобы пользоватся модулями нужно в package.json указать

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node auto_exports.js && node --experimental-modules server.mjs"
},
```

все файлы которые являются модулями должны быть не js, а mjs

это файл auto_exports.js он нужен для таво чтобы происходил експорт

```
let fs = require("fs");
let path = require("path");

function getFiles(dir, files_){
  files_ = files_ || [];
    let files = fs.readdirSync(dir);

    for(let f of files){
        let name = dir + "/" + f;
        if(fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()){
            if(f == "node_modules") continue;
            getFiles(name, files_);
        }else{
            files_.push(name);
        }
    }
    return files_;
}

for(let name of getFiles(path.resolve()).filter(f => f.slice(-3) == "mjs")){
    let f = fs.readFileSync(name, "utf8");
    let lm = f.split("\n");
    let words = [];
    for(let l of lm){
        let ks = ["let", "const", "function", "function*", "class"];
        for(let s of ks){
            s += " ";
            if(l.slice(0,s.length) == s){
                let r = l.slice(s.length).match(/^\ *([a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ_0-9]+)/);
                if(r) words.push(r[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    if(lm[lm.length - 1].slice(0,6) == "export"){
        lm = lm.slice(0,-1);
    }
    lm.push("export {" + words.join(",") + "};");
    if(process.argv[2] == 1) lm = lm.slice(0,-1);
    fs.writeFile(name, lm.join("\n"), function(err){});
}
```